# How to create multidimensional array in python from list?

Tags: python

I have a list containing elements like

```
list1 = [['Test Name', 'Results', 'Units', 'Bio. Ref. Interval'], 
         ['Cholesterol, Total', '243.00', 'mg/dL', '<200.00'], 
         ['Triglycerides', '365.00', 'mg/dL', '<150.00'], 
         ['HDL Cholesterol', '48.56', 'mg/dL', '>50.00'], 
         ['LDL Cholesterol, Calculated', '121.44', 'mg/dL', '<100.00'], 
         ['VLDL Cholesterol, Calculated *', '73.00', 'mg/dL', '<30.00'], 
         ['Non-HDL Cholesterol', '194', 'mg/dL', '<130']]
```

I want to use `list1[0]` that is, `['Test Name', 'Results', 'Units', 'Bio. Ref. Interval']` to make it as key and want output something like the following multidimensional dictionary.

```
{
 { Testname : 'Cholesterol, Total' {
                        Result : '243.00',
                        Units :  'mg/dL',
                        Bio. Ref. Interval : '<200.00'
                    },....
  ....
 { Testname : 'Non-HDL Cholesterol' { Result : '194', Units : 'mg/dL', Bio. Ref. Interval : '<130'}}
}
```

I'm newbie to python. Help out please.

Comment: Do you want your key to be in one whole string: `"Testname : 'Non-HDL Cholesterol'"`? Your expected output is not a valid dict

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need unique keys for the dictionary so you can do something like this:

```
dict1 = {f'Test {j}': {list1[0][i]: list1[j][i] for i in range(4)} for j in range(1, len(list1))}
```

Which will have the following output.

```
{'Test 1': {'Test Name': 'Cholesterol, Total', 'Results': '243.00', 'Units': 'mg/dL', 'Bio. Ref. Interval': '<200.00'},
 'Test 2': {'Test Name': 'Triglycerides', 'Results': '365.00', 'Units': 'mg/dL', 'Bio. Ref. Interval': '<150.00'},
 'Test 3': {'Test Name': 'HDL Cholesterol', 'Results': '48.56', 'Units': 'mg/dL', 'Bio. Ref. Interval': '>50.00'},
 'Test 4': {'Test Name': 'LDL Cholesterol, Calculated', 'Results': '121.44', 'Units': 'mg/dL', 'Bio. Ref. Interval': '<100.00'},
 'Test 5': {'Test Name': 'VLDL Cholesterol, Calculated *', 'Results': '73.00', 'Units': 'mg/dL', 'Bio. Ref. Interval': '<30.00'},
 'Test 6': {'Test Name': 'Non-HDL Cholesterol', 'Results': '194', 'Units': 'mg/dL', 'Bio. Ref. Interval': '<130'}}
```

Comment: Thank you soo much. That is what exactly I want :)

Answer (score 2):

There are several method to convert list into a dictionary.One is dict comprehension and other one is zip method.

refer this -> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-convert-a-list-to-dictionary/

Answer (score 1):

**Output will be list of dictionary. Not dictionary of dictionary because we require key here.**

1. You need to know how to iterate list and slice operation on list.
2. You should known how  `zip` function works.
3. and `append` method of list.

**Code**:

```
list1 = [
    ['Test Name', 'Results', 'Units', 'Bio. Ref. Interval'], 
    ['Cholesterol, Total', '243.00', 'mg/dL', '<200.00'], 
    ['Triglycerides', '365.00', 'mg/dL', '<150.00'], 
    ['HDL Cholesterol', '48.56', 'mg/dL', '>50.00'], 
    ['LDL Cholesterol, Calculated', '121.44', 'mg/dL', '<100.00'], 
    ['VLDL Cholesterol, Calculated *', '73.00', 'mg/dL', '<30.00'], 
    ['Non-HDL Cholesterol', '194', 'mg/dL', '<130']
]

# Output will be list of dictionary. Not dictionary of dictionary because we require key here.

keys = list1[0]

output_list = []
for item in list1[1:]:
    _tmp = {}
    for key, value in zip(keys, item):
        _tmp[key] = value
    output_list.append(_tmp)

print("output_list:", output_list)
```

**List Comprehension**:

```
output_list = [dict(zip(keys, item)) for item in list1[1:]]

print("output_list:", output_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

The requested output cannot be a dictionary(since there are no keys mentioned) but rather list of dictionaries only.

```
my_list_of_dictionaries = [{k:i[list1[0].index(k)] for k in list1[0]} for i in list1[1:]]
```